# Problems with the laptop's default keyboard if pressing the shift key doesn't work normally

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, kali-linux, shift

The problem arose at a time when I was still using Windows 7.  I'm not sure if the problem is really  my Windows 7 setup.

When I use my Toshiba laptop's default keyboard, from 2010 (it seems) and the OS is Windows 7, when I want to press the button

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>@</kbd>

there suddenly the symbol drops to the bottom of the line, normally it should be on the same line when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, right?

And instead I ignore my Windows 7, I try to switch to kali Linux, and I think the problem is solved by switching OS, it's still the same.

Now I'm using a keyboard from Logitech, and it's working fine but I want my laptop keyboard back to normal, does anyone know how to fix it?

More detail this time I used the default keyboard:

> 1. This line I will try to fill in the symbol by pressing Left <kbd>@</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>
> 2. This line I will try to fill in the symbol by pressing Right <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>@</kbd>

and this time I will compare using an external keyboard:

> 1. I will try to fill this line by pressing Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>@</kbd> (normally)
> 2. This line I will try to fill in the symbol by pressing Right <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>@</kbd> (normal)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: basically a normal keyboard when pressing SHIFT, the character that appears always in front of the cursor does not change places, while my default keyboard always switches places when I press SHIFT.

Comment: I agree with "Community Bot"... you are soliloquizing and not asking.